# D3.js Zoom and Pan to element on Click

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming

I've gone through a few posts as to how to zoom to an element within a larger SVG that has a zoom and pan function on its own as well, but without any luck. I have a large map where you can zoom and pan to elements manually which works but i want it to zoom and pan to any element itself when clicked on such an element. I can't seem to get the right values for the transformation.

Here's a jsfiddle of what i've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/1gyjd2xt/1/

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg-container svg");

var container = svg.select("#container");

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}


d3.selectAll(".text").on("click", function () {

    var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")),
        x = t.translate[0],
        y = t.translate[1];

    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    var scale = 10;

    //Zoom to element 
                //svg.transition()
                  //.call(zoom
                  //.translate( calculate X, calculate Y)
                  //.scale(scale).event);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I managed to find the right coordinates. I just have to call the zoom again and use the `X` and `Y`.

I got from the text element and then it zooms with the object being in the top left corner because that's where the origin of your view is.

So, if I then add the `height` and `width` of my view divided by 2, then I have the zoom in the center. Using the `zoom behavior`, it won't mess up my standard zoom and pan with the mouse, and always uses the current `X` and `Y` to zoom to my clicked element.

```
svg.transition().duration(3000)
.call(zoom.translate([((x * -scale) + (svgWidth / 2)), ((y * -scale) + svgHeight / 2)])
.scale(scale).event);
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1gyjd2xt/4/

Comment: The zooming feels a bit strange I would say. Is this your actual intention?

Comment: I managed to make it work better by adding a size to the zoom behaviour. It says here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior that a size is needed to support smooth zooming during transitions.